# Adding field to enum

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

I have to write an acceptance test for a project. Inside this project there is  a public final enum which contains another enum with methods. I should add new values at run time but I have no idea how to achieve this result. The language I am using is Java.

Can you help me?

Comment: Why do you need to add values to an enum in order to write an acceptance test??

Comment: Because I have to load new values from FIT tables, and this values are represented by enum type into the system

Comment: The point of an enum is to provide a statically constrained set of values - if your requirement is for a open ended set of values that can be read dynamically don't use an enum. Your only options are too change the code to return instance of classes that are constructed from the data in your table or statically add new fields to the enum.

Comment: I cannot chose the type of the object. I am testing an object which is a enum.

Comment: The java type system is telling you the code does not meet your requirements. If the range of values that must be returned is not expressed by the enum then the code has failed the acceptance test as some of your scenarios cannot even be expressed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically create entries in an Enum in java.  I'd suggest using a map to do something like this, but it won't be an enum.

Comment: I cannot change the code! I have to return a type that is a enum

Comment: Sounds like you're doing the XY Anti-pattern here.  What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to do this : http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue161.html but more general. I don't have any switch.

Answer (score 0):

Have your enum implement an interface which declares the getter-methods to access the field on the enum you would like to extend. In client code, change all methods that take the enum to the interface. With this design, you can easily add new values for your test.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an list (E.G. LinkedList etc.) and use the values() method of an enum
to get the initial values (the values of the enum) into the list.  Then you can add the new values to the list at run time, E.G.:

To iterate over values of an enum, just use values(); example assumes proper declaration of public Enum Month {...}:

```
1. for (Month month : Month.values()) {  
2.  //do something  
3. }
```

This is a URL with info on using values() with an enum:

```
http://www.coderanch.com/t/410234/java/java/Iteration-Enum
```